# iOS Development - Round Rect Buttons move down for sub menu

Tags: ios, xcode, button, menu, rect

I have spent about 3 months now trying to figure out a problem and have finally turned to help. I have a menu with 5 round rect buttons. I want to know if theres a way I can make it so when I click the first button, the other four move down, to create space for a submenu under the first button. The same for the second, third, fourth, and fifth button. At the same time however, I want to make it so if the first button is clicked, the other four move down, and say the third one is clicked, four and five move even more down, and a scroll view launches when they can no longer all be displayed on the screen at once. Thanks in advance for all help :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can in fact do this. Here is an example for you. The jist is that you make a new IBAction which movies the coordinates when you press the button. So, if you have your method for what happens when you press the button, just add this to it:

```
button.frame = CGRectMake(button.frame.origin.x, (button.frame.origin.y), button.frame.size.width, button.frame.size.height);
```

As for changing where the buttons move, make a method like that and just add to the coordinates in order to move it. For example, if you wanted to move the above button up 150 pixels, you would do this:

```
button.frame = CGRectMake(button.frame.origin.x, (button.frame.origin.y - 150.0), button.frame.size.width, button.frame.size.height);
```

See what I did there? You just add or subtract from the frame to move the buttons where you want them to go.

Comment: It's up to you to take it as far as you need it to go, but that will provide the foundation.

Comment: Wow..thank you so much. Just one more quick question though, how would I make it so when the button is pushed a second time, everything moves back into place? Thanks in advance:)

Comment: add another method that subtracts/adds the exact coordinates that you changed to cancel them out and bring the change back to 0, putting them back in place. Dont forget to give the checkmark if this help you out =]

Comment: Don't Worry...I gave it a checkmark because it did help me out a lot:) But Im still confused on how to add that method.

Comment: Here's what I'd do: 1. Declare a boolean that is default false in the method connected to the button pressed action
2. Add a conditional that checks to see if the boolean is false, and if it is, it moves the other buttons after you press the original button, and once they move set the boolean to true. 
3. In the second part of the conditional, check to see if the boolean is true, and if it is, move the buttons back by canceling out the coordinates you moved them once you press the original button, and then have this conditional set the boolean back to false.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put them all inside a tableView instead of a UIScrollView, (which is a scrollView itself) and override the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` methods according to your will. You may have to write a custom UITableViewCell for this and have a property to understand whether the cell is selected or not and switch it inside the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. Use tableView's beginUpdates and endUpdates methods at the end of the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to animate the movement of other subviews automatically.

You can also write animations for that by changing the origin of the UIButtons to move them, but I have tried it and with that number of subviews it becomes really messy, believe me. To see examplary code with dynamic row height and only one selectable cell you can have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13293380/936957. To enable multiple selection you can either have a NSMutableArray at the viewController/ UITableView's delegate or put a property of your custom UITableViewCell, like I've said before, both should work fine.