# how do I expand cell in tableview dynamically?

Tags: ios, tableview

I have only one `cell` with a button in a `tableview`. The `cell` height is defined in

```
tableView:tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:
```

The cell height is 40;

When I click the button, how do I change the cell height to 80?
thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a property and `@synthesize` it:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSIndexPath* selectedRowIndex;
```

Override `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and `heightForRowAtIndexPath` methods:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if(selectedRowIndex && indexPath.row == selectedRowIndex.row) {

        //[_yourTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES]; If you only want the cell to get bigger
        selectedRowIndex = nil;

    }

    else {  self.selectedRowIndex = [indexPath retain];   }

    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView endUpdates];
}

- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

if (tableView == _yourTableView) {


    if(selectedRowIndex && indexPath.row == selectedRowIndex.row){

        return 80;
    }

    // Cell isn't selected so return single height
    return 40;

}

else return 0;
}
```

Because of the beginUpdates and endUpdates lines this should animate the cell height.

Comment: hi, let me try  [tableView beginUpdates]; [tableView endUpdates]; I think I need to how to redraw the table.

Comment: hi, I have tested. [tableView beginUpdates]; [tableView endUpdates]; can trigger redraw tableview. thanks. my question has solved.

Answer (score 1):

Here is [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) for UITableView Delegate. You need to set a delegate and set the function is  - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath. Remember the return value is CGFloat, so return 80.0 instead of 80. Hope this helps.. Read more about other delegate functions in the documentation...

Comment: hi, thanks, however, I think you misunderstand my purpose. I would like to know how to change cell height after I have shown table.

Answer (score 0):

When the button is pressed you should set a variable to a value that indicates it has been pressed, then call reloadData on your tableView. This will make tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath to be called again.

In tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath check the variable that tells you if the button has been pressed or not and return 80 if it has been pressed

Comment: yep. I want to know how to trigger something to draw the table view.