# How to give animation to a height change on a UITableViewCell when selected?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm using a `UITableView`.

There is list of data displayed in the table. I want to animate the cell when a user clicks on it.

How do I do it?

Comment: Have you done any research? Show the code you tried and explain what is does wrong.

Comment: Check the link mentioned below:

[Click Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293131/how-do-i-expand-cell-in-tableview-dynamically)

Answer (score 0):

Try it. I think it will help you.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

  [tableView beginUpdates];
  [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
  [tableView endUpdates];

}
```